# Paradox in conservation of energy

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors, dipole

> Let us assume there is a constant electric field in an interested region (finite volume)and a non-conducting object is thrown into it with speed $v$ and now take the second scenario with the same region of the constant electric field but now a conducting object of the same volume as before is thrown into it with same speed $v$?

So, comparing total energy in the first and second case would both energy be same? keeping in mind that in metallic object electric field will be zero due to electrons movement and the dipole will be formed.

So in terse,would there be difference in total energy in both the scenario?

Comment: The metallic conductor is electrically neutral

Comment: the total energy is given by three contributions: the integral on the whole volume of the electric energy density $\sim \frac{\vec E^2}{2}$, the energy of the (possible) dipole, and the kinetic energy which is same in both cases assuming masses don't vary. In the first case you have no dipole and you integrate on the whole available volume. In the second you have the energy of the dipole but inside the conductor $\vec E$ is 0 so you have less energy. I would guess the energy of the dipole exactly matches the "hole" due to the missing sphere, but I haven't come up with a full calculation yet.